# Azure - C# Concurrency - Best Practices

Tags: c#, azure, concurrency, parallel-processing

We are scraping an Web based API using Microsoft Azure. The issue is that there is SO much data to retrieve (there are combinations/permutations involved).

If we use a standard Web Job approach, we calculated it would take about 200 years to process all the data we want to get - and we would like our data to be refreshed every week.

Each request/response from the API takes about a 0.5-1.0 seconds to process. Request size is on average 20000 bytes and the average response is 35000 bytes. I believe the total number of requests is in the millions.

**Another way to think about this question would be: how would you use Azure to Web scrape - and make sure you don't overload (in terms of memory + network) the VM it's running on? (I don't think you need too much CPU processing in this case).**

What we have tried so far:

1. Used **Service Bus Queues/Worker Roles** scaled to 8 small VMs - but this caused a lot of network errors to occur (there must be some network limit to how much EACH worker role VM can handle).
2. Used **Service Bus Queues/Continuous Web Job** scaled to 8 small VMs - but this seems to work slower - and even scaled, doesn't give us too much control on what's happening behind the scenes. (We don't REALLY know how many VMs are up).

**It seems that these things are built for CPU calculation - not for Web/API scraping.**

Just to clarify: I throw my requests into a queue - which then get picked up by my multiple VMs for processing to get the responses. That's how I was using the queues. Each VM was using the ServiceBusTrigger class as prescribed by microsoft.

1. Is it better to have a lot small VMs or few massive VMs?
2. What C# classes should we be looking at?
3. What are the technical best practices when trying to do something like this on Azure?

Comment: You are confusing scalability with parallel processing. Queues and Service Bus improve scalability. Parallel processing is handled by the Task Parallel Library, PLINQ etc. A single process can handle a *lot* of concurrent HTTP requests as most of the time it's simply waiting for a response.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain properly - I throw my **requests** into a queue - which then get picked up by my multiple VMs for processing to get the responses. That's how I was using the queues. Each VM was using TPL as prescribed by MS to use the `ServiceBusTrigger` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually a web scraper is something that I have up and running, in Azure, for quite some time now :-)

AFAIK there is no 'magic bullet'. Scraping a lot of sources with deadlines is quite hard.

How it works (the most important things):

- I use worker roles and C# code for the code itself.
- For scheduling, I use the queue storage. I put crawling tasks on the queue with a timeout (e.g. 'when to crawl then') and have the scraper pull them off. You can put triggers on the queue size to ensure you meet deadlines in terms of speed -- personally I don't need them.
- SQL Azure is slow, so I don't use that. Instead, I only use table storage for storing the scraped items. Note that updating data might be quite complex.
- Don't use too much threading; instead, use async IO for all network traffic.
- Also you might have to consider that extra threads require extra memory (parse trees can become quite big) - so there's a trade-off there... I do recall using some threads, but it's really just a few.

Note that probably this does require you to re-design and re-implement your complete web scraper if you're now using a threaded approach.. then again, there are some benefits:

- Table storage and queue storage are cheap.
- I currently use a single Extra Small VM to scrape well over a thousand web sources.
- Inbound network traffic is for free.
- As such, the result is quite cheap as well; I'm sure it's much less than the alternatives.

As for classes that I use... well, that's a bit of a long list. I'm using HttpWebRequest for the async HTTP requests and the Azure SDK -- but all the rest is hand crafted (and not open source).

P.S.: This doesn't just hold for Azure; most of this also holds for on-premise scrapers.

Answer (score 2):

I have some experience with scraping so I will share my thoughts.

1. **It seems that these things are built for CPU calculation - not for Web/API scraping.**

They are built for dynamic scaling which given your task is not something you really need.

2. **How to make sure you don't overload the VM?**

Measure the response times and error rates and tune you code to lower them.

3. **I don't think you need too much CPU processing in this case.**

Depends on how much data is coming in each second and what you are doing with it. More complex parsing on quickly incoming data (if you decide to do it on the same machine) will eat up CPU pretty quickly.

4. **8 small VMs caused a lot of network errors to occur (there must be some network limit)**

The smaller the VMs the less shared resources they get. There are throughput limits and then there is an issue with your neighbors sharing the actual hardware with you. Often, the smaller your instance size the more trouble you run into.

5. **Is it better to have a lot small VMs or few massive VMs?**

In my experience, smaller VMs are too crippled. However, your mileage may vary and it all depends on the particular task and its solution implementation. Really, you have to measure yourself in your environment.

6. **What C# classes should we be looking at?**
7. **What are the technical best practices when trying to do something like this on Azure?**

With high throughput scraping you should be looking at infrastructure. You will have different latency in different Azure datacenters, and different experience with network latency/sustained throughput at different VM sizes, and depending on who in particular is sharing the hardware with you. The best practice is to try and find what works best for you - change datacenters, VM sizes and otherwise experiment.

Azure may not be the best solution to this problem (unless you are on a spending spree). 8 small VMs is $450 a month. It is enough to pay for an unmanaged dedicated server with 256Gb of RAM, 40 hardware threads and 500Mbps - 1Gbps (or even up to several Gbps bursts) of quality network bandwidth without latency issues.

For you budget, you will have a dedicated server that you *cannot overload*. You will have more than enough RAM to deal with async pinning (if you decide to go async), or enough hardware threads for multi-threaded synchronous IO which gives the best throughput (if you choose to go synchronous with a fixed-size threadpool).

On a sidenote, depending on the API specifics, it might turn out that your main issue will be the API owner simply throttling you down to a crawl when you start to put too much pressure on the API endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for your input - have you ever used Azure for scraping or the underlining architecture it provides for scraping?

Comment: I entertained the idea and tried it. However, having faced the same issues you are describing I did not get very far. It was just too slow, expensive in terms of both money and amount of work required. In the end, it was just too much trouble for no apparent benefit over dedicated servers. I did not need dynamic scaling, and it turned out dedicated hardware and proper infrastructure trumps everything else.